# Creating sepa mandates with stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I wanna create payment option for  PaymentMethodType of `['sepa_debit', 'card']` to pay for subscriptions and as far as I know for sepa one needs a mandate to ensure there really is an agreement.

I wonder how to set that up. The api https://stripe.com/docs/api/mandates does not provide a method to create mandates, so I tried via `setupIntent.create` in my node app. I tried like this:

```
function createSI(mandateData, customer){
    const setupIntent = await this.stripe.setupIntents.create({
        customer: company.stripeCustomerId,
        payment_method_types: ['sepa_debit', 'card'],            
        confirm: true,
        mandate_data: {
           customer_acceptance: {
              type: 'online',
              online: {
                 ip_address: mandateData.ip,
                 user_agent: mandateData.userAgent
              }
           }
        }
    });
    return  setupIntent.client_secret;
}
```

That however results in an error: "

> You cannot confirm this SetupIntent because it's missing a payment
> method. Update the SetupIntent with a payment method and then confirm
> it again..

Now I am confused as to my understanding I need this setupIntent to get the `client_secret` to pass to `stripe.elements` in the frontend where the user chooses the payment method out of the two options I allow.

Any idea how to setup a proper sepa mandate if the customer picks sepa debit and still allow the customer the choice to choose between different payment options?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that

```
            confirm: true,
            mandate_data: {
               customer_acceptance: {
                  type: 'online',
                  online: {
                     ip_address: mandateData.ip,
                     user_agent: mandateData.userAgent
                  }
               }
            }
```

is not needed since without it I generate a payment method that is not linked to a mandate but the setupintent generated links to mandate that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "mandate_1MWGeHJgnOZBUP8a7CqJXatQ",
  "object": "mandate",
  "customer_acceptance": {
    "accepted_at": 1675159269,
    "online": {
      "ip_address": "188.194.197.44",
      "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    },
    "type": "online"
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "multi_use": {},
  "payment_method": "pm_1MWGeHJgnOZBUP8aMzlN7Th2",
  "payment_method_details": {
    "sepa_debit": {
      "reference": "MMWMNDRP9PYNMEB8",
      "url": "https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/sepa_debit/file/src_1MWGeHJgnOZBUP8aiAIM8PUQ/src_client_secret_IkXKK4JdRHCGl8IO5ZudWIJn"
    },
    "type": "sepa_debit"
  },
  "status": "active",
  "type": "multi_use"
}
```

Note: Seems one needs to search for a setupintent with the resulting paymentMethodId and that one then has the mandate info to get the mandate for the paymentmethod.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a SetupIntent while passing `mandate_data` without a payment method which is why you’re seeing the above error. The reference you should be looking at is [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/sepa-debit/set-up-payment?platform=web). Stripe Elements is a set of prebuilt UI components for collecting payment details. With Stripe Elements, you can collect the [payment method details and mandate acknowledgement](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/sepa-debit/set-up-payment?platform=web#web-collect-payment-method-details). This creates the accepted mandate, but you’ll need to communicate these terms to your customers in your form or through email.

Alternatively, you can use the [Payment Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) for setting up future payments. The Payment Element helps collect payment details for various payment methods. Depending on the payment method, it dynamically requests the necessary details and handles the mandate when needed.